# Use generating function to check how many solutions are to get balls from boxes and roll dices

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

In the box are 4 red balls, 5 blue balls and 2 yellow balls. How many possible solutions there are to get 7 balls from box to have at least 1 red ball and exactly 2 blue balls?

I'm not sure I am doing it correct. My answer is:

Taking blue possibility is

$1 +x^2$

Taking red possibility is

$(1 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)$

Taking yellow possibility is

($1+x^1+x^2$)

So the generating function looks like

$  (1 +x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)* (1+x^1+x^2)* (1+ x^2) $

And the coefficient of x^7 is 3

So there are only 3 ways to take them

This same problem i got with exercise:

Using generation function show on how much possibilities you can throw n points on k dices.

I was trying to do this like:

n - number of points

k - number of dices

I made function for this, but I dont know what to do later.

$(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^k$ // 6 walls in dice

And here i'm stuck.

Comment: You have exactly 2 blue balls, so you might as well consider the number of possible ways of drawing 5 balls from a box with 4 red balls and 2 yellow balls, where you have at least 1 red ball.

Comment: Also, your generating function is wrong. Since you have exactly 2 blue balls, the corresponding term would be $x^2$ and not $(1 + x^2)$. Also, you have at least 1 red ball, so the corresponding term would be $(x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)$. The number $1$ can be interpreted as $x^0$ which means you're not picking any balls of that color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think your first example is correct. We have between $1$ and $4$ red balls, exactly $2$ balls, and at most $2$ yellow balls. You have an extra $1$ in two of your expressions (I am not sure why).

$$[x^7](x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(x^2)(1+x+x^2) = 2$$

Your answer to the dice question is exactly correct. You can make it a little more compact

$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^k = \left(\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}\right)^k$$

Comment: Thank you so much for fast answer, I am studying for about 14 hours for exam and I make some mistakes :)

Comment: No problem - I think it might be that seeing $1$ makes you think you've selected $1$ object, but really $1=x^0$ corresponds to selecting no object, which can be tricky in a rush. Good luck on the exam! :)